# Class method execute twice inside of if ()

Tags: php

```
if ( $this->guardian() ) { return $this->guardian(); }<--will this execute method twice?

$guardian = $this->guardian();
if ( $guardian ) { return $guardian; }
```

I have a question, if I place class method inside of if and return method, will this execute method twice? (its nice and clean, but I dont want execute twice)

Comment: yes, it wiil. The second way is the right way to do it

Comment: but first way looks so nice and clean lol

Comment: Yes it will call the function, I think the second variant will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will, unless it returns 0, null, false, etc. You can do

```
if ( $ret = $this->guardian() ) { return $ret; }
```

Answer (score 3):

The first option will execute the method twice, because you are calling it 2 times.

But the second option will store the result of the method in the var `$guardian`.
Your second way it's the correct way, because calling a function `X` more than one time when it's not needed it's not right and inefficient, this will consume a lot more of resources.